# Error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: c#, parsing

This code can work with one of the web, but with some sites it back error messages like this, I do not know how to edit (Error in stars)

```
var document = webBrowser1.Document;
var documentAsIHtmlDocument3 = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument3)document.DomDocument;
var htmlString = documentAsIHtmlDocument3.documentElement.innerHTML;

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmlString);

// Sử dụng node để lấy tin
HtmlNodeCollection texts = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='footer']/p");
string kq = "";

// cho vòng lặp để lấy kết quả
foreach (var item in texts)
{
    kq += item.InnerText + Environment.NewLine;
}

richTextBox1.Text = kq;
```

HTML code:

```html
<div id="divTop" >
    <div id="text-conent" style="width: 500px; float: right;"></div>
    <div id="grid" style="margin-removed 505px; height: 700px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `code PHP:` section seems to be out of context and adds nothing to the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that on the pages where this is successful there exists a `div` with the `id` of `footer`

But on other pages where this fails no such div exists.

So it seems like your logic may need to change to make the search expression that `doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes` more forgiving.

Alternatively create a few more search strings that would work if your original fails:

```
if(texts == null){
    texts = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("some other search string");
}
```

etc.

Comment: but I do not understand, when I use the back simple_html_dom obtain information in div tags, so now use DocumentNode.SelectNodes returns null ?
 

include 'simple_html_dom.php';
if(isset($_GET['date']))
{
    $url = 'http://10.8.32.20/Default.aspx?Menu=' . $_GET['date'];
}
 
$html = file_get_html('http://localhost:81/curl/thu.php');
 
echo '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>';
foreach($html->find('div#divTop') as $e)
    echo $e->innertext . '<br>';
 
?>